# ldap server connection in esb wso2

Tags: search, ldap, wso2, connection, esb

Could we connect to ldap server without providing any value in securityPrincipal and securityCredentials parameters in init in esb wso2?
If not, what exactly should be the value we need to provide for securityPrincipal and securityCredentials parameters in init operation for connecting to ldap server in esb wso2.

I am getting below error while calling searchEntry operation after init operation in esb wso2.

```
 {
"error": {
    "errorMessage": "simple bind failed: ldapxxx.xxx.com:389",
    "errorCode": 7000002
}
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by setting below  parameters.

```
"securityPrincipal":"",
   "securityCredentials":"",
   "secureConnection":"true",
   "disableSSLCertificateChecking":"true",
```